# Why Github Dependency Graph has some packages that don't get rendered as links

Tags: github

In a github repository I own most of the dependencies are rendered as links - but some of them, including one of my own Github repository dependencies (aor-component-factory), don't.

[image]

Is it because they are not that popular and they weren't indexed yet or there is some configuration/code that needs to be added to those repositories? Thanks!

Comment: You should reach out to GitHub support.

Comment: @osowskit I did yesterday - let's see what they say

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is for repo renamed (the OP confirms it wasn't).

Another reason is the path used to reference dependencies in the `package.json`

```
 zifnab87/ra-component-factory 
 vs.
 ra-component-factory
```

The former should work better.

Following [this tweet](https://twitter.com/JGamblin/status/931180494154338304), try and apply to your repo the [`jgamblin/GithubDependencyCheck`](https://github.com/jgamblin/GithubDependencyCheck) tools to see if that particular dependency in gray is reported any differently.

From the [OP Michail Michailidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986160/michail-michailidis)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747319/why-github-dependency-graph-has-some-packages-that-dont-get-rendered-as-links/47339980#comment82672645_47339980), it seems that was a GitHub bug that was since fixed (Dec. 2017).

Comment: this was the case even before the rename too

Comment: OK. Any answer from GitHub support?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis I have rewritten the answer to include another possible reason.

Comment: I never got any answer from Github support - now things just work - it seems that it was some kind of a bug from their side or they slowly parsed lesser known repositories

Comment: @MichailMichailidis OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.